# How to resolve many-to-many relationship without creating a junction class in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In my DB I have three table `USER`, `PERMISSION` and a junction table `USER_PERMISSIONS`. As you can see I have clear many-to-many relationship.

And here is the question. I'm using a Hibernate. Is it possible to use only two classes, `User` and `Permissions` without creating a junction class `UserPermissions`? I mean can I use some kind of annotations to include my junction table `USER_PERMISSIONS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to use the @JoinTable and @JoinColumn annotation. Example below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USER_PERMISSIONS", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERM_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
private Collection<Permissions> permissions;
```

A full working example with bidirectionaly many to many can be found in here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany